# Showing uniform convergence of $\frac{1}{g}$ on compact set

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(g_n)$ be a sequence of continuous functions that converges uniformly to $g$ on a compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}$. If $g(x) \ne0$ on $K$, show $(\frac{1}{g_n})$ converges uniformly on $K$ to $\frac{1}{g}$.

**My attempt:**

Let $\epsilon>0$. By assumption, there is some natural $N$ so that $|g(x)-g_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for any $n\geq N$ and any $x\in K$. For $n\geq N$, we have $|\frac{1}{g_n(x)} -\frac{1}{g(x)}|=|g(x)-g_n(x)|\cdot \frac{1}{|g_n(x)g(x)|}<\frac{\epsilon}{|g_n(x)g(x)|}$ for any $x\in K$. Now, since $K$ is compact, each $g_n$ is bounded by some positive number. By uniform convergence, it follows that the $g_n$ are uniformly bounded, say by $S>0$. Also, we know $g$ is continuous on $K$, hence is bounded by some $M>0$. Thus, we get $|g_n(x)g(x)|\leq SM$ for any $n$ and $x\in K$.

But what I need is some positive *lower* bound, correct? I'm not sure if this would be enough or even how to find a suitable one. Could I manipulate the upper bound (i.e., $SM$) to get it?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Fixed the typos, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding a positive lower bound for $\{|g(x)|:x\in K\}$ : The continuous image of a compact space is compact.

Let $g:K\to \mathbb R$ be continuous, where $K$ is compact.  The image $g(K)$ is compact, hence closed in $\mathbb R.$

So if $0\not \in g(K)$  then $0\not \in \overline {g(K)},$ so for some $r>0$ we have $\phi =\overline {g(K)}\cap (-r,r)=g(K)\cap (-r,r)$ and hence $|g(x)|\geq r$ for all $x\in K$.

Comment: Thanks! I will still need a uniform lower bound for the $g_n$, correct?

Comment: Let $\|g-g_n\|=\sup \{|g_n(x)-g(x)|:x\in K\}.$... We have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|g_n-g\|=0.$ (Uniform convergence.)...  Let $\inf\; \{|g(x)|:x\in K\}=r>0$. Then for all but finitely many $n$ we have $\|g_n-g\|<r/2$....And if  $\|g_n-g\|<r/2$ then for all $x\in K$ we have $|g_n(x)|\geq  |g(x)|-|g(x)-g_n(x)|> r-(r/2)=r/2.$

Answer (score 0):

Since $g_n$ is continuous on $K$, then it follows that $g$ is continuous on $K$ , therefore, by the continuity of $g$ and the fact that $g\ne0 $ on $K$, without loss of generality we can assume that $g(x)>M>0,\forall x\in K$, where $M$ is a fixed number. Now, choose $N$ to be sufficiently large such that $\sup|g_n(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon<M,\forall n>N$. We have $$g_n(x)g(x)>(g(x)-\epsilon)g(x)>M(M-\epsilon)$$. Note that $M$ is independent of $\epsilon$, thus we can conclude that: for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, there exists an  $N$, such that $ \sup\left|1/g_n(x)-1/g(x)\right|<\epsilon/M(M-\epsilon)<\epsilon',\forall n>N$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $g(x) \neq 0$ on $K$ and $g$ is continuous as a uniform limit on $K$ of continuous functions then (I'm supposing without loss of generality that $g$ is positive)

$$\exists \, \eta > 0 \, \, / \, \, \forall x \in K \, \, \, \, g(x) > \eta$$

[On second thought, I'll be thorough: If $|g|$ has no lower bound then you can find a sequence $(x_{p})$ such as $|g(x_{p})| \rightarrow 0$. Because $K$ is compact, you can always extract a sub-sequence $(x_{\varphi(p)})$ from $(x_{p})$ that converges to some $x^{*} \in K$. Hence, $x_{\varphi(p)} \rightarrow x^{*}$ and continuity of $g$  gives $g(x^{*}) = 0$].

You should now agree with the above statement, that $g$ is bounded from below.

Now uniform convergence gives
$$\forall \, \epsilon > 0 \, \, \, \exists \, N \, \, / \, \, \forall n > N \, \, \, \sup_{x \in K} |g_{n}(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon$$

By taking $\epsilon$ small enough, say ($\epsilon < \eta/2$) then (because $g(x) > \eta$)

$$\exists \, N \, \, / \, \, \forall n > N \, \, \text{ and } \forall x \in K \, \, \, g_{n}(x) > \eta/2$$

You now have you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution:

**Abbott 6.2.8.** By the continuous limit theorem, $g$ is continuous on $K$. Since $g$ is continuous on the compact set $K$, $g[K]$ is also compact. Since for each $x \in K$, $g(x) \neq 0$, it follows from the fact that $g[K]$ is closed that $0$ is not a limit point of $g$. Thus there exists $\varepsilon_1 > 0$ such that $V_{\varepsilon_1}(0) \subseteq (g[K])^c$, i.e. for each $x \in K$, $|g(x)| \geq \varepsilon_1$. Since $(g_n) \to g$ uniformly on $K$, there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $n \geq N_1$, for each $x \in K$, $|g_n(x) - g(x)| < \frac{\varepsilon_1}{2}$. This implies that for each $n \geq N_1$, for each $x \in K$, $|g_n(x)| > \frac{\varepsilon_1}{2}$. Now let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Find $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $n \geq N_2$, for each $x \in K$, $|g_n(x) - g(x)| < \frac{\varepsilon\varepsilon_1^2}{2}$. Let $N = \max(N_1, N_2)$. Then for each $n \geq N$, for each $x \in K$, $|\frac{1}{g_n(x)} - \frac{1}{g(x)}| = |\frac{g(x) - g_n(x)}{g_n(x)g(x)}| = \frac{|g(x) - g_n(x)|}{|g_n(x)||g(x)|} < \frac{\frac{\varepsilon\varepsilon_1^2}{2}}{\frac{\varepsilon_1}{2}\varepsilon_1} = \varepsilon$. Thus $(\frac{1}{g_n}) \to \frac{1}{g}$ uniformly on $K$.